# Join two collections with different fields in Magento to select by date

Tags: php, mysql, magento, model-view-controller, magento-1.9

I have two tables in Magento database with only two common fields (date and customer_id) with below details:

> First table name "order" with fields (customer_id, date, order_id)
>
> Second table name "request" with fields (customer_id, date, request_id, request_type)

I can select the last 10 records sorted by date from each collection separately, But how i can select last 10 records from both tables combined sorted by date and show the order_id if it is from "order" table and show request_id and request_type if it is from "request" table ?

I can select from the collections as bellow:

```
   $orders = Mage::getModel('Custommodule_Order/Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 1)->setOrder('date', 'DESC')->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(1); 

   $requests = Mage::getModel('Custommodule_Request/Request')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 1)->setOrder('date', 'DESC')->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(1);

foreach($orders as $order){
echo $order->getOrderId();
}

foreach($requests as $request){
echo $order->getRequestId();
}
```

Comment: Where is your table? columns for the table? And also please show us what you've done.

Comment: @MahmoudMustafa If you can edit and update your question with table structure some one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` with extra fields:

```
(SELECT t1.id, `t1.date` dte, 1 sourcetable FROM t1) 
UNION
(SELECT t2.id, `t2.date`, 2 sourcetable FROM t2) 
 ORDER BY dte DESC
 LIMIT 10;
```

`sourcetable` column will tell you from which table you got the row.